# Deflecting a belt under tension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring

I have a belt setup around two pulleys and I want to measure the tension on the belt by depressing it at the middle with a force gauge. [image]

My colleague approaches this problem by taking the perpendicular components of the tension, doing [image]
I don’t think this is the right way to approach this as that equation is basically describing a situation where we are pulling that point of contact with a force T but that is not what we are doing. Also, the tension would increase as d does so that’s another thing to incorporate.

I think the problem should be treated as a spring problem but I can’t figure out an equation that describes deflecting a string under some tension T.

Comment: All real springs are nonlinear; the key is to keep the deflection small so the springlike behavior can be characterized without changing the geometry or the tension by very much. If you wish, you can augment your colleague's solution by adding a correction term for the increased tension from the increased length.

Answer (score 1):

I'm voting with your colleague.

Everything comes down the the force it takes to deflect the belt at the point of contact, and since this is for a static situation, action equals reaction.  The reaction is the belt pushing back against the defection, and that's going to be $2T\sin\theta$.  And this is all about the belt at the point of the reaction, so it doesn't matter whether the belt is being pushed or pulled or under a force field, or whether the tension is due to a spring, or pulley, or gravity, etc.  The action is the force, $F$, and since action equals reaction, $F = 2T\sin\theta$.